# Mongo (w/ mLab) find what query has been executed at a certain time?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mlab

Is there any kind of query logs/history of what query has been executed at a certain time?

If yes, how/where to find it?

If no, is there a way to find what caused a db peak some hours ago?

Thanks

Comment: queries that took longer than 100ms should be in the mongod log.  If it was faster than that, it probably wasn't recorded anywhere

Comment: @Joe the query was definitely longer than 100ms, is the mongod log that you are talking about a log file on the server or is it the db.oplog collection?

Comment: It is a file on the server.